# jQuery 3 - method defined within an object literal - .map() always returning array with 0 of length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following object with methods that I use in my application:

```
var myObject = {
    // ...
    loadData: function () {
        this.loader();

        var tbASP = [];
        var tbID = $('.portlet-body div').map(function () {
            return this.id;
        }).get();

        $('[data-asp]').each(function () {
            tbASP.push($(this).attr("data-asp"));
        });

        console.log(tbID);

        for (var i = 0; i < tbID.length; i++) {
            $(tbID[i]).load('api/' + tbASP[i] + '.asp', function () {
                $(this).find('div[id^="gf"]').each(function () {
                    var tabela = $(this).attr("id").substring(3);
                    var funcao = $(this).data("funcao");

                    this.main(funcao, tabela);

                    $('#tb-' + tabela + ' button.bt-qtd-valor').click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $('.qtd.' + tabela + ', .vlr.' + tabela).toggle();
                        $('.mensal.' + tabela + ', .acumulado.' + tabela).toggle();
                        this.main(funcao, tabela);
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    }
    // ...
};
```

My HTML is as it follows:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div id="faixa-de-valor-portlet" class="portlet">
        <div class="portlet-title">
            <div class="caption caption-green">
                <i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i>
                <span class="caption-subject text-uppercase"> Contratos Ativos - Por Faixa de Valor</span>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                <!-- Onde ficarão as ações dos portlets -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portlet-body">
            <div id="faixa-de-valor" data-tipo="<%=TipoRelatorios%>" data-asp="tbCarteiraAtiva_Faixa_Valor" class="simples"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div id="ano-de-contratacao-portlet" class="portlet">
        <div class="portlet-title">
            <div class="caption caption-green">
                <i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i>
                <span class="caption-subject text-uppercase"> Contratos Ativos - Por Ano de Contratação</span>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portlet-body">
            <div id="ano-de-contratacao" data-tipo="<%=TipoRelatorios%>" data-asp="tbCarteiraAtivo_Assinatura" class="simples"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The HTML code above is repeated several times in my Web page.

I am trying to get the `ID`s and the `data-asp` from the `DIV` that are inside the `DIV`s with `.portlet-body` class.

I already tried the following:

```
var minhaFuncao = function(){
    var tbASP = [];
    var tbID = [];

    $(".portlet-body").find("div").each(function () {
        tbID.push("#" + $(this).attr("id"));
        tbASP.push($(this).data("asp"));
    });    

   $("#resultado").html(tbID.length +"/"+ tbASP.length);
};

$(function(){ minhaFuncao(); });
```

And [**it worked as you can see here**](https://jsfiddle.net/e8fvky08/1/)! That's a combination of .each(), .find and .data() from jQuery and .push().

The big detail here: it works in JSFiddle, but does not work if I define the function above as a method within an object.

The result when I execute the code is always:

```
[]
    length: 0
    __proto__: Array []
```

Now I'm trying to use the .map() and the result is the same.

It's probably a stupid question but I can't find a way of solving it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Okay! It's embarrassing and I was right: it was a stupid question!

The whole problem was caused because I was putting a loader as the initial content of my .portlet-body DIV, so there were no DIVs inside of them, just a  tag with a Font Awesome loader!

I'm sorry, guys!

And thank you all for your time.